# KClass reference for nullable values

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

In Kotlin, when declaring getting a KClass for a type, such as String::class (which represents values whose type will be String), is there a syntax to indicate that the value is nullable (ie represente String? values instead of String).

The context is that I'm trying to generate Kotlin classes using KotlinPoet but all properties I create (with PropertySpec.builder) are not nullable (String for instance, when what I actually want is String?).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case someone needs this : As of KotlinPoet 0.3.0, the syntax is :

```
PropertySpec.builder("myVar", String::class.asTypeName().asNullable()).mutable(true).initializer("%S", null)
```

to produce :

```
var myVar:String? = null
```

Answer (score 9):

No. Kotlin has [Nullable types and Non-Null Types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types) but it does not have a concept of nullable *classes* and non-null *classes*. A [`KType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/) is a classifier plus nullability where a classifier can be a [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/).

KotlinPoet [0.1.0](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-010) did not have a way to represent nullable types but support for such was added in [0.2.0](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-020) via `TypeName.asNullable`. e.g.:

```
val type = TypeName.get(String::class).asNullable()
```

Comment: Seems like this was removed, it's not available in KotlinPoet `1.12.0`. Arguably, Matej's answer is the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

As for KotlinPoet 1.1.0:

```
Any::class.asTypeName().copy(nullable = true)
```

https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet#nullable-types

Comment: `.asNullable()` seems to have been removed in the newer version of KotlinPoet, so I have also used this solution

Answer (score 2):

KotlinPoet [0.2.0](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-020) has just been released, and added support for nullable types, through `asNullable()` calls. For example:

```
PropertySpec.builder("name", TypeName.get(String::class).asNullable()).build()
```

... will create:

```
val name: java.lang.String?
```

---

Note that as the release notes mention, some function signatures in 0.2.0 have been flipped from the (type, name) order to use (name, type) order instead, so don't be scared when upgrading breaks your code.

Comment: Answer from mfulton26 gives relevant information. I selected this one as it gives the actual code that solves my issue with KotlinPoet (after upgrading to 0.2.0). Thanks to both of you for the detailed answers.

Comment: TypeName.get(String::class) doesn't work anymore in 0.3.0. I can seem to be able to make it work with the new TypeName class. If anyone knows what the correct syntax is now, please let me know !

Comment: Hey, I think what you're supposed to use now is `String::class.asTypeName().asNullable()`. You will need an import for this that IntelliJ doesn't seem to find on its own though: `import com.squareup.kotlinpoet.TypeName.Companion.asTypeName`

Comment: Yes, I was confused because of the IntelliJ bug that produced an error when I tried to use asTypeName(). Works fine with the import indeed.